# OOP_PHP - Difference between an Instance of a classA and an empty classB that inherits from classA

Tags: php, oop

In case that the classA is fully public . I need to know what is the difference . in others words . what is the benefits that i got when (extending an empty classB from fully public class A) instead of (using an instance of that classA) . 
and vice versa  ..

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: ah sorry i forgot. its PHP

Answer (score 2):

There is could be several cases.

1. While refactoring you need to rename your class but keep legacy code working.
2. It's an exception where the type is used as a discriminator.
3. It's an alias. For example, mysql has synonyms `tinyint(1)` and `boolean`.
4. ...

I think that there could be more cases.

Comment: #2 ("It's an exception") can be more generally thought of as "where the *type* is used as a discriminator".

Answer (score 0):

In reality, there is no real difference in functionally.

That said, there would be a small margin of added load time (not worth worrying about) as you're reading from the back class.

That said, why would you want to run code via a blank extended class?

The purpose of extending a class into another is to add functionality from the extended class, for parts that aren't really needed elsewhere.

For example, you have your main database class that covers database connection and all select, insert etc.

Then you have your users in the database and you require a few additional functions based on their user level.

Instead of complicating the database class for the users, extend the class into your users class and then you can just use the new function on top of it, without having to edit the first.